# GIT undo branch -D

Tags: git

After merged my changes on the main remote branch, I wanted to remove the name of my branch and leave the branch where it is. Only delete its name (in my team they don't like branches with names, unless they are releases).

So I did the following:

```
git branch -d branch_2b_deleted
error: The branch 'branch_2b_deleted' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D branch_2b_deleted'
git branch -D branch_deleted
git push origin :remoteHead
```

But the whole branch was removed, and also on the header the changes disappeared. Is possible to undo that "branch -D" command?

Else I will must redo the work and wait for a pull-request. I also don't know why the message that the branch was not fully merget, it seemed to me that all the changes where on the remote branch.

---edit---
I solved by re-doing the merge, (now  it's difficult to explain by word how the tree looked like).
After that, I had another problem, because when i wanted to assign a tag to a branchA, this tag was assigned to branchB. My console told me that i am on branchA, but GIT pointed to branchB. So i did:

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> branchA
```

To solve, i did:

```
git pull origin branchA
```

and this did the work. I was not on branchA even if on the console it was written that i am on branchA (after:  git checkout branchA). The system should advice in such cases I think, not telling that I "simply" was on branchA...

Comment: Please read a tutorial on git branches, the fact that git told you that it was not fully merged and then you went ahead and asked it to delete your branch anyway, and then afterwards are surprised that the branch was deleted indicates that you really need to learn how branches in git works.

Comment: The branch was merged and not error was on it during merge.

Maybe some bug? There is something wrong. Now for example i am on branch A, I add a tag on it and the tag appears on another branch.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a utility in git called git reflog, where all your changes are recorded. If you want to recover that branch do the folowing:

Do git reflog and find the SHA1 for the commit at the tip of your deleted branch, then just

`git checkout -b <branch> <sha>`

Comment: In reflog I can find the previous command, when i "left" that branch in order to delete it, but not the command of deletion.

Comment: Yes, the "left" action also work for this. Use the SHA of that action in the `git checkout` command I suggested you

Answer (score 0):

You confuse `is not fully merged` with `is not pushed`.
If you e. g. are on local branch `master` and you try to delete branch `foo` which **was not** merged into `master` you get this message.
If you are on local branch `bar` and you try to delete the same branch `foo` but it **was** merged into `bar`, you do not get the message.
This is to make sure you don't delete a branch that you didn't merge yet but want to merge in the future, as you will probably loose commits.

To find your branch, you can look at the `reflog` of `HEAD` by just doing `git reflog` and search for the last time when you had that branch checked out. That should be your last commit on that branch. If not, you might find it with `git fsck --lost-found` as dangling object.

If you found your latest commit on the branch, just recreate it with `git branch your-branch <found commit-ish>`, or `git checkout -b your-branch <found commit-ish>`.

To just delete a branch on the remote side without deleting the local branch, just use the last of your commands, i. e. `git push origin :remote-branch` which means "push nothing to remote-branch on origin" and thus delete it on the origin without touching your local branch.